# When is the do keyword required in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example, does the presence or absence of `do` in the following code affect the behavior of the program at all?

```
while true do
    puts "Hi"
    break
end

while true
    puts "Hi"
    break
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [The Ruby Programming Language](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/) book Section 5.2.1:

> The `do` keyword in a `while` or `until` loop is like the `then` keyword in an
> `if` statement: it may be omitted altogether as long as a newline (or
> semicolon) appears between the loop condition and the loop body.

So, no, it won't change the behavior, it's just optional syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Let's find out!

For a quick answer we can look at Ruby's documentation and find http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop which states that

> The do keyword is optional.

Ok so these two examples are equivalent but are they identical? They might do the same thing but maybe there's a reason to favor one over the other. We can look at the AST these examples generate and see if there's any difference.

```
> gem install ruby_parser
> irb

> require 'ruby_parser'
=> true
> with_do = <<-END
 while true do
     puts "Hi"
     break
 end
 END
=> "while true do\n    puts \"Hi\"\n    break\nend\n"
> without_do = <<-END
 while true
     puts "Hi"
     break
 end
 END
=> "while true\n    puts \"Hi\"\n    break\nend\n"
> RubyParser.new.parse with_do
=> s(:while, s(:true), s(:block, s(:call, nil, :puts, s(:str, "Hi")), s(:break)), true)
> RubyParser.new.parse without_do
=> s(:while, s(:true), s(:block, s(:call, nil, :puts, s(:str, "Hi")), s(:break)), true)
```

Nope. These two examples execute the exact same instructions so we can pick whichever style we find easier to read. A common preference is to omit the `do` when possible: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-multiline-while-do

Comment: This is interesting (I must look at `ruby_parser`), but unnecessarily difficult to read with all the `irb` prompts.  I suggest you remove them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can edit the prompts out and help this question be better looking.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot, I almost never edit what others have written. As I see it, they own the words, so I can do no more than suggest changes. (Very old school, I know.) Can you guess my reaction when others edit what I've written? :-)

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, does that read more easily for you? I'm always unsure if I should strive for clean examples or literal copies of output. I'm not sure which one is easier for someone else to follow and reproduce.

Comment: @CarySwoveland aww you should. It would enhance the quality of the content for the rest of the community :) Think of it this way if someone is lost and asks for directions and someone else starts helping, but you notice part of their directions are ambiguous, would you think "I shouldn't butt in, they own those directions they're telling". Or would you help straighten out the directions?